# Returning null when trying to upload image file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload a photo using MVC but it is returning null, I have already used HttpPostedFileBase, yet I still don't know why I am not getting the file. I saw youtube tutorials where they use HTTPPost in their Controller Action Result, but mine is different and I can't update it. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrUpdateOperator(Operator_Profiles operator_Profiles) {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(operator_Profiles.ImageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(operator_Profiles.ImageFile.FileName);
        fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
        operator_Profiles.OperatorPic = "../Content/assets/images/operators/" + fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../Content/assets/images/operators/"), fileName);
        operator_Profiles.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

        using (db) {
            if (operator_Profiles.OperatorID > 0) {
                db.Entry(operator_Profiles).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            } else {
                db.Operator_Profiles.Add(operator_Profiles);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public partial class Operator_Profiles
{
    public int OperatorID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Upload Operator Photo")]
    public string OperatorPic { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Birthdate { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form name="operatorForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">
        <span id="headertitle"></span>
    </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.OperatorID)
    <div class="form-row mb-3">
        <div class="col-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.OperatorPic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            <input type="file" name="ImageFile" class="form-control-file" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Lastname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Lastname, "Invalid Lastname", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Firstname, "Invalid Firstname", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", required = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "Invalid Email", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "tel", required = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhoneNumber, "Invalid Phone Number", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Birthdate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Birthdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", required = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Birthdate, "Invalid Birthdate", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @{
                var genderList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" }, }, "Value", "Text");
            }
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Gender, genderList, "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control", required = true })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Gender, "Please choose a Gender", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @{
                var statusList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Clear", Value = "Clear" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Suspended", Value = "Suspended" }, }, "Value", "Text");
            }
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Status, statusList, "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control", required = true })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Status, "Invalid Status", new { @class = "invalid-feedback" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-auto" onclick="SaveOperatorProfile()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function SaveOperatorProfile() {
var modal = $("#operatorModal");
var form = $('form[name = operatorForm]');
form.validate({
    errorClass: 'is-invalid',
    validClass: 'is-valid',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    },
    errorPlacement: function () {
        // Done in highlight/unhighlight
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('Operator Profile has been successfuly saved.');
    }
});
if (!form.valid()) {
    return;
} else {
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.post("/Admin/CreateOrUpdateOperator", data, function (res) {
        if (res) {
            modal.modal('hide');
            OprTable.ajax.reload();
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: What was the code when you tried HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: The reason you are getting null on the ImageFile is because you are not asking for it in your ActionResult. Is that ActionResult even a POST method?

Comment: I didn't use HTTPPost for that ActionResult. I am posting it using the JS code

Comment: I didn't include some of the rows in my form in the View Code, there are some inputs for other informations so I need to serialize it when I post it using the js code that I provided

Answer (score 1):

So after some modifications, It worked! I used FormData instead of serializing my form.

My form now calls the ajax post function if submitted using this modification:

```
<form name="operatorForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="SaveOperatorProfile(this)">
```

Then this is my js code

```
function SaveOperatorProfile(formData) {
var modal = $("#operatorModal");
var form = $('form[name = operatorForm]');
form.validate({
    errorClass: 'is-invalid',
    validClass: 'is-valid',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    },
    errorPlacement: function () {
        // Done in highlight/unhighlight
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('Operator Profile has been successfuly saved.');
    }
});
if (!form.valid()) {
    return;
} else {
    var ajaxConfig = {
        type: "post",
        url: "/Admin/CreateOrUpdateOperator",
        data: new FormData(formData),
        success: function (res) {
            if (res) {
                modal.modal('hide');
                OprTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        }   
    }

    if ($(formData).attr('enctype') == "multipart/form-data") {
        ajaxConfig["contentType"] = false;
        ajaxConfig["processData"] = false;
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting anything in your ActionResult from the form because you are not asking for it. The "name" of your image object is "ImageFile" as per your HTML input. This needs to match up in your POST method. For example,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrUpdateOperator(HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile, FormCollection col) {
    Operater_Profiles operater_Profiles = new Operator_Profiles();
    string myString1 = col["SomeName1"].ToString();
    string myString2 = col["SomeName2"].ToString();
}
```

The name of the parameter needs to match with the name from the HTML.

EDIT:

In addition to your controller, you need to actually mark it as a POST method, it's highly recommended. To do this, just add the attribute [HttpPost] before the method declaration.

You are using jquery/js to also post via an ajax method. This is not really how you should be doing this since you aren't doing any dynamic page loading here. You should be making full use of the MVC architecture - why else are you using ASP.NET's MVC?

Instead of using the jquery, you can instead change your  input to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ACTIONNAME", "CONTROLLERNAME", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    <input type="file" name="ImageFile" class="form-control-file" />
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Lastname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @name = "SomeName1" })
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @name = "SomeName2" })
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", @name = "SomeName3" })

}
```

As you can see, I added names to your data you are posting. These names can be grabbed via FormCollection in the controller.

Comment: I am sorry, In my Javascript code, I am trying to post it using that. So what should my controller function would be? 2 parameter? one for the serialized form and the second one is for the image?

Comment: Yes, it should be both. However, even if you are posting it with js, you should declare the method as a POST action in the controller.

Comment: Is there any modification for the js code? How can I include the file in the js post, as of now it only post the serialized form as "data"

Comment: Adter looking at it again, arent you only using the Imageafile input in your controller? You arent posting anything else are you?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the road trying to answer. You actually have a number of issues. I'll edit my answer for you.

Comment: Done editing my view code, there are other inputs so I need to serialize it when I post it. The problem is how can I include the file when I post it

Comment: The reason why I am not using the beginform style is because I also got a ActionResult function where when I edit a profile it fills out all the information to the textboxes of the view. Is that the only way I can use in order to receive the file?

Comment: Wouldnt you just have a different view for the edit profile page? But there probqbly is a way to post the image, too. Ive never posted an image in ajax but i will look it up

Comment: Currently trying the formdata but still figuring it out how can I include in ajax post

Comment: You can post the image in ajax, theres a lot of google results for it. form.append() is what youre looking for

Comment: You will still need to grab the image via httppostedfilebase with the matching input name